# what is the use of ! in object Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found something that I think is really strange. A `!` inside an object

```
interface MyObj {
  a?: string,
  b: number
}

const toto: string = "test";

const obj: MyObj = {
  a: toto!,
  b: 0
}
```

I can't figure out what is the toto!

Answer (score 0):

A new ! post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded.
[See here](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/what-is-the-use-of-exclamation-mark-operator-in-typescript/#:%7E:text=The%20description%20contains%20many%20fancy,is%20not%20null%20or%20undefined.)